# dc sweep convergence issue for cmos inverter

Tags: inverter, cmos, spice, ngspice, dc-sweep

I am having some convergence issue with DC sweep for a CMOS inverter.

To duplicate the exact issue, see the following log as well as the attached netlist files, together with [modelcard.nmos](https://github.com/promach/frequency_trap/blob/development/modelcard.nmos) and [modelcard.pmos](https://github.com/promach/frequency_trap/blob/development/modelcard.pmos)

I have tried various suggestions online (such as bypassing .op analysis , using smaller dc sweep step, use .ic initial condition, add parasitic resistance to circuit nodes), but those do not help in my case.

[image: dc sweep circuit analysis of cmos inverter]

**ngspice run log**

```
[phung@archlinux frequency_trap]$ make test_CMOS_Inverter.net
gnetlist -L ../.. -g spice-noqsi test_CMOS_Inverter.sch -o test_CMOS_Inverter.net
reading specific gafrcLoading schematic [/home/phung/Documents/Grive/Personal/Analog/Active_Inductor/frequency_trap/test_CMOS_Inverter.sch]
[phung@archlinux frequency_trap]$ ngspice test_CMOS_Inverter.net

ngspice-30 : Circuit level simulation program
The U. C. Berkeley CAD Group
Copyright 1985-1994, Regents of the University of California.
Please get your ngspice manual from http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html
Please file your bug-reports at http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/bugrep.html
Creation Date: Thu Jan 3 04:39:51 UTC 2019

Circuit: * gnetlist -l ../.. -g spice-noqsi -o test_cmos_inverter.net test_cmos_inverter.sch

Doing analysis at TEMP = 25.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

No. of Data Rows : 1
@m.x1.m1[gds] = 0.000000e+00
@m.x1.m1[gm] = 2.080796e-03
@m.x1.m2[gds] = 5.094415e-03
@m.x1.m2[gm] = 1.145951e-03
cout = 2.997462e+00
v_ip_out#branch = -2.99746e-11
vd#branch = -1.71460e-03
vdd = 3.300000e+00
vin = 1.650000e+00
vin#branch = 0.000000e+00
vout = 2.997462e+00
vs#branch = 1.714603e-03
vss = 0.000000e+00
Doing analysis at TEMP = 25.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

^Ceference value : 0.00000e+00
Interrupted once . . .
doAnalyses: Too many iterations without convergence

dc simulation interrupted
Doing analysis at TEMP = 25.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000

No. of Data Rows : 100
ngspice 1224 -> listing
* gnetlist -l ../.. -g spice-noqsi -o test_cmos_inverter.net test_cmos_inverter.sch

 2 : .param supply=3.3v
 3 : .global gnd
 6 : x1 vin vout inv1
 7 : vs vss 0 0v
 8 : vin vin 0 dc {supply/2} ac 1
 9 : vd vdd 0 {supply}
10 : v_ip_out cout vout dc 0v
11 : r1 0 cout 100g
12 : cout 0 cout 1n
14 : .model n1 nmos
15 : .model p1 pmos
16 : .global vdd vss
21 : .subckt inv1 2 1
23 : m2 1 2 vdd vdd p1 l=0.4u w=3u m=25
24 : m1 1 2 vss vss n1 l=1.2u w=3u m=25
26 : .ends
28 : .control
29 : save all @m.x1.m1[gm]
30 : save all @m.x1.m2[gm]
31 : save all @m.x1.m1[gds]
32 : save all @m.x1.m2[gds]
33 : op
34 : print all
35 : dc vin 0 vd 0.1
36 : ac lin 100 1 10g
37 : let gm=(i(v_ip_out))/vin
38 : plot gm
39 : print gm > transconductance_of_cmos_inverter.log
40 : .endc
13 : .options temp=25
41 : .end

ngspice 1225 -> listing expand
* gnetlist -l ../.. -g spice-noqsi -o test_cmos_inverter.net test_cmos_inverter.sch

23 : m.x1.m2 vout vin vdd vdd p1 l=0.4u w=3u m=25
24 : m.x1.m1 vout vin vss vss n1 l=1.2u w=3u m=25
 7 : vs vss 0 0v
 8 : vin vin 0 dc    1.64999999999999991e+00   ac 1
 9 : vd vdd 0    3.29999999999999982e+00 
10 : v_ip_out cout vout dc 0v
11 : r1 0 cout 100g
12 : cout 0 cout 1n
14 : .model n1 nmos
15 : .model p1 pmos
13 : .options temp=25
26 : .end

ngspice 1226 ->
```

**test_CMOS_Inverter.net**

```
* gnetlist -L ../.. -g spice-noqsi -o test_CMOS_Inverter.net test_CMOS_Inverter.sch
* SPICE file generated by spice-noqsi version 20170819
* Send requests or bug reports to jpd@noqsi.com
X1 Vin vout INV1
Vs Vss GND 0V
Vin Vin GND AC 1
Vd Vdd GND 'SUPPLY'
V_IP_out Cout vout DC 0V  
R2 GND Vin 100G      
R1 GND Cout 100G      
Cout GND Cout 1n      
.PARAM SUPPLY=3.3v
.options TEMP=25
.IC v(Vin)=1.65 v(Vout)=1.65
.MODEL n1 NMOS
.MODEL p1 PMOS
.GLOBAL Vdd Vss
.INCLUDE CMOS_Inverter.net
.control
save all @m.x1.m1[gm]
save all @m.x1.m2[gm]
save all @m.x1.m1[gds]
save all @m.x1.m2[gds]
*op
print all
dc Vin 0 Vd 0.01
ac lin 100 1 10G
let Gm=(i(v_ip_out))/Vin
plot Gm
print Gm > Transconductance_of_CMOS_inverter.log
.endc
```

**CMOS_Inverter.net**

```
* gnetlist -L ../.. -g spice-noqsi -o CMOS_Inverter.net CMOS_Inverter.sch
* SPICE file generated by spice-noqsi version 20170819
* Send requests or bug reports to jpd@noqsi.com
.subckt INV1 2 1
*
M2 1 2 Vdd Vdd P1  l=0.4u w=3u         m=25
M1 1 2 Vss Vss N1  l=1.2u w=3u         m=25
*
.ENDS
```

Comment: Try to reduce the humongous `100G` to `1G`, or less (`1Meg..100Meg` shouldn't interfere too much), maybe add a `1m` series resistance to the `1n` capacitor. Compared they have a great dynamic range difference that may confuse the matrix solver. Also try some `1m..100m` series resistance to the supplies, just for the testing.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Capacitances are ignored in Spice DC analysis.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I just read that the convergence issue starts after the OP... The issue is then indeed most likely a numerical one.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen the suggestion of reducing 100G to 1Meg for both R1 and R2 does not help

Comment: @SvenB The netlist is confusing, it shows both `ac` and `dc` cards, thought I am mostly used to LTspice.

Comment: @kevin Have you tried adding series resistances to at least the driving source? Some `10` Ohm resistor won't hurt. The voltage sources have zero internal resistance, and the *MOS have finite capacitance; that may result in extremely large values for currents.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen adding series 10 OHM to supply voltage also does not help

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen See the modification that I had done so far which do not help in DC sweep convergence

https://i.imgur.com/mUdFInJ.png

Comment: @kevin998x Well, unless the *MOS models themselves are not to blame, I'm out of ideas for now. Looking at the links for the models, in the first lines it says to not use these models except for benchmarking purposes. Maybe this is the problem? What happens if you use other models, quasi-real ones? Even ridiculous for this application, such as IRF540 (should be models around). The expanded listing also shows a `100G` res, maybe also try to change that, too? When in doubt, grab the hammer. If that doesn't work, either, maybe it's a bug (though I'd put that last on the list).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.IC` statements?

Comment: Also, as per @aconcernedcitizen's remark, have you tried removing the `.MODEL` statements as they should have been included using the `.INCLUDE` statements?

Comment: @SvenB [DC Sweep convergence problem](https://i.imgur.com/eskQrfP.png) solved using this [solution](https://sourceforge.net/p/ngspice/discussion/120973/thread/9cc3a1dfa0/?limit=25#5087)